# division and remainders

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

When you divide, it will not always result in whole number. Sometimes there will be numbers left over. You can either end the problem with a remainder or use decimal points to get a decimal number. When using a remainder, I notice the following:

Given a dividend 0 through 20 and a divisor of 5:

0 divided by 5 has remainder 0, since 5 doesn't go into 0

1 divided by 5 has remainder 1, since 5 doesn't go into 1

2 divided by 5 has remainder 2, since 5 doesn't go into 2

3 divided by 5 has remainder 3, since 5 doesn't go into 3

4 divided by 5 has remainder 4, since 5 doesn't go into 4

5 divided by 5 has remainder 0, since 5 divided by 5 divides evenly

6 divided by 5 has remainder 1, since 6 / 5 is 1r1

7 divided by 5 has remainder 2, since 7 / 5 is 1r2

8 divided by 5 has remainder 3, since 8 / 5 is 1r3

9 divided by 5 has remainder 4, since 8 / 5 is 1r4

10 divided by 5 has remainder 0, since 10 divided by 5 divides evenly

11 divided by 5 has remainder 1, since 11 /5 is 2r1

12 divided by 5 has remainder 2, since 12 /5 is 2r2

13 divided by 5 has remainder 3, since 13 /5 is 2r3

14 divided by 5 has remainder 4, since 14 /5 is 2r4

And this pattern of 0,1,2,3,4 remainders appears to go on forever when we hit a number with a common multiple of 5. What is this called?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic would be the name for this branch of Mathematics that looks at remainders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called division of the integers, *[modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)* $5.\;$ You've identified the *equivalence classes* of the the integers, modulo $5$. Indeed, we denote the set of these elements as $\mathbb Z_5 = \{[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]\}$,  which has precisely 5 elements. Note: you'll also see $\mathbb Z_5 = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$.

**Every** integer $m$ can be expressed in the form $m = qn + r$, where $q, n, r$ are integers, $q$ is the (integer) quotient, $n$ the divisor, and $r$ the remainder, with $0\leq r\lt n$. In your experiment, $n = 5$.